# How can i combine two queries when using distinct

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am currently in a project where i have used a for loop create a list of tuples with the form (id_one, id_two) where the ranking_id's from the two queries below are equal.

It is important that the query picks the most newly updated row from the database if there are several rows with equal ranking_id. Else the order does not matter.

I was wondering whether there is a fast single query to replace the for loop and the two single queries. Help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

#query one

```
cur.execute(f''' SELECT DISTINCT ON (ranking_id) ranking_id, id
FROM {my_table}
WHERE user_id = ({user_id_one})
ORDER BY ranking_id ASC, updated_at DESC''')    
list_one = cur.fetchall()
```

#query two

```
cur.execute(f''' SELECT DISTINCT ON (ranking_id) ranking_id, id
FROM {my_table}
WHERE user_id = ({user_id_two})
ORDER BY ranking_id ASC, updated_at DESC''')    
list_two = cur.fetchall()
```

I am using python and postgresql.(i am not asking how to write the for loop)

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT user_id,
                     ranking_id, 
                     id, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ranking_id ASC, updated_at DESC) rn
              FROM {my_table} )
SELECT user_id, ranking_id, id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thx. However I don't understand how this works. The answer also doesn't seem to use user_id_one and user_id_two

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your queries to two users by modifying the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, ranking_id) ranking_id, id
FROM {my_table}
WHERE user_id IN ({user_id_one}, {user_id_one})
ORDER BY user_id, ranking_id ASC, updated_at DESC;
```